# My bash script won't execute commands after kill command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logstash, kill

I am trying to make a bash script that is killing a process and then it's going to do other stuff.

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep logstash | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $PID
kill -9 $PID
echo "logstash process is stopped"
rm /home/user/test.csv
echo "test.csv is deleted."
rm /home/example.txt
echo "example.txt is deleted."
```

When I run the script, it kills `logstash` as exptected but it terminates also my whole script.

I've also tried: `kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'logstash' | awk '{print $2}')`.
With this command, my script will be terminated as well.

Comment: What's your script name? Why are you using `kill -9`?

Comment: My script is stoplogstash.sh and i am using kill to force stopping the process.

Comment: Give your scrip a name which does not contain "logstash" :-)

Comment: the name of your script is making grep to return its own PID. Please grep it as '[ ]logstash[ ]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should correct your issue :

```
PID=$( ps -ef | grep -E '[ ]logstash[ ]' | grep -v "grep" | head -1 | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PID
kill -9 $PID
echo "logstash process is stopped"
rm /home/user/test.csv
echo "test.csv is deleted."
rm /home/example.txt
echo "example.txt is deleted."
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your script name includes "logstash".

As a consequence, PID is filled with 2 values, and the kill command kills your script as well.

Rename your script without "logstash" in the name should fix the issue.